# Make a droppable div dynamically expand when i drop an element into it

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, draggable

When I drag the question1 & question2 into questionslots i want the questionSlots div to expand its size dynamically when the second question is dropped into it.
i.e. both the questions should be accomadated and visible in when dropped in the questionSlots.

Html:

```
<div id="questionsHolder">
    <div id="question1" class="question">
        1. This is a random question.
    </div>
</div>
<div id="questionsHolder1">
    <div id="question2" class="question1">
        2. This is a random question.
    </div>
</div>
 <br>
     <br><br><br><br><br>
 <div id="questionSlots"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.question {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 200;
}
.question1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 200;
}

#questionSlots div {
  /*margin-top: 25px;*/
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  height: 46px;
  background: #ddf;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#questionsHolder{
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  /*height: 46px;*/
  background: grey;
}
#questionsHolder1{
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  /*height: 46px;*/
  background: grey;
}

#questionSlots .question.hovered {
  background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
$( init );

function init() {
    // Create droppable
            $('<div id="slot1"></div>').appendTo( '#questionSlots' ).droppable( {
              accept: '#questionsHolder div,#questionsHolder1 div',

              hoverClass: 'hovered',
                drop:function(event, ui){
                    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
                }
            } );

    $('#questionsHolder').droppable( {
              //accept: '#slot1 div',
              hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
                 drop:function(event, ui){
                    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
                }  

            } );

    // Make question draggable
        $("#question1").draggable( {
            cursor: 'move',
            //snap: '#content',
            revert: 'invalid'
            } );
              // Make question draggable
        $("#question2").draggable( {
            cursor: 'move',
            //snap: '#content',
            revert: 'invalid'
            } );

    /*function handleQuestionDrop( event, ui ) {
        // Make sure no more questions get dropped at droppable
        // position it directly on top of the slot
        $(this).droppable({ accept: ('#' + $(ui.draggable).attr('id') ) });
        ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
        ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );

    }*/
    }
```

The js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6zGLk/14/

It would be better if you could help me by editing the js fiddle code and forward your link.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: question 2 isn't in your fiddle

Comment: Ops! My bad put up the old link. Here's the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/6zGLk/14/  @MichaelCoker

Comment: is this kinda what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/6zGLk/15/

Comment: yes awesome stuff! put it up as an answer so I can give it a green tick. Thanks bro. @MichaelCoker

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641469/when-a-draggable-div-is-hovered-on-droppable-div-change-the-background-color-of could you help me with this one also! @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to use `$.appendTo()` with `$.sortable()`. Updated your functions and CSS a bit, too.

```js
$(init);

function init() {
  $('<div id="slot1"></div>').appendTo('#questionSlots').droppable({
    accept: '#questionsHolder div,#questionsHolder1 div',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  }).sortable();

  $('#questionsHolder, #questionsHolder1').droppable({
    //accept: '#slot1 div',
    hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(this);
    }

  });

  $("#question1,#question2").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: 'invalid',
  });

}
```

```css
.question {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.question1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#questionSlots div {
  /*margin-top: 25px;*/
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  min-height: 46px;
  background: #ddf;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#questionsHolder {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  height: 46px;
  background: grey;
}

#questionsHolder1 {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: dashed;
  width: 496px;
  height: 46px;
  background: grey;
}

#questionSlots .question.hovered {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionsHolder">
  <div id="question1" class="question">
    1. This is a random question.
  </div>
</div>
<div id="questionsHolder1">
  <div id="question2" class="question1">
    2. This is a random question.
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="questionSlots"></div>
```

Comment: This code is working only in js fiddle. When I save it in a .html file and try to run it on my pc locally the code doesn't seem to be working why is that happening?    Please help me out!

Comment: @stephencarvalho it isn't just working in jsfiddle - it's working in the post I made here, too. There's nothing wrong with the code (it's just html, css, and JS) - it's something with your implementation, computer, server, who knows... and not only can I not see that, but it's beyond the scope of this problem. It's up to you to create the problem in the post, and we fix the problem in the post.

Comment: @stephencarvalho but the first step would be to look in your browser console for errors.

Comment: @stephencarvalho hah, yeah those will definitely help ;) glad you got it figured out!